# absolute DIV positioning with mozilla V.S. safari V.S. Chrome V.S. IE

Tags: google-chrome, html, safari, positioning, mozilla

I'm having trouble with the browser compatible div positioning. I'm doing an image map with buttons on top of it in separate div's. These div's tend to move around in firefox, in safari and chrome everything is okay.

They tend to move down a bit.

Changing the doctype seems to influence the rendering in firefox. But none of the doctype's seem to work.

Check the Algiers button on this link in firefox and you'll see what I mean.

http://kareldc.com/grimonprez/index_js_animatie_clicks.html

Any help = very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<body>` element is still using the browser's default margin and padding values (8px), which may account for the gap you're seeing.

Another thing to note is that while your images have explicit heights, the `<div>`s surrounding them are actually taller than those images.

For instance, the image you reference is 37px tall. It's surrounded by the `#button_8_algiers` div.

- In Firefox, that element is 43px high, which is 6 pixels taller than the image -- the exact number of pixel whitespace you have.
- In chrome, the element is 41px high, which is 4 pixels taller than the image. Chrome is rendering it OK for some reason, though.

Comment: Yes, always try to neutralize padding and margins with a CSS reset: http://www.google.com/search?q=reset+css

Comment: I'm thinking of doing a browser check in jquery and maybe adding a "-10px" to all top values of all css elements... but that's a last resort kind of a thing I guess...

Comment: Thanks! I got it all fixed, I also had a problem with the nesting and the absolute and relative positioning. But now I got it all fixed!