# Absolute html layout is broken when zooming

Tags: html, css

I am new to html positioning. I mostly use absolute positioning like:

```
#div {
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:30%;
}
```

When I zoom the page in Google Chrome,layout is broken. All elements get bigger in size and also move to the right and get positioned chaotic to each other. When I zoom the same page in Safari, it's just zoomed right(like a static picture).

Can you explain please, what is wrong? How do I position it correctly?

Comment: _"Can you explain please, what is wrong?"_ Using absolute positioning.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257158/zooming-on-chrome-causes-css-positioning-issues

Comment: Zooming? Why do you want to zoom in?

Comment: maybe you can find your response [here][1] .


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214338/absolute-div-positioning-with-mozilla-v-s-safari-v-s-chrome-v-s-ie

Comment: @Marciano User can zoom page

Comment: @j08691 relative positioning is okay??

Comment: That depends totally on your layout and what you need. If you have a plain vanilla layout there's usually very little reason to use absolute positioning. Remember that absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their nearest positioned ancestor, and they are removed from the flow of the document.

Comment: Pretty old article but may help explain why and when you should use absolute positioning. http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/absolute-positioning-pitfalls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using percentages. When you zoom in the percentage is going to be based off the container. If you don't like that then don't use percentages. As you zoom in and out the container is adjusting to a new size and so will the elements in the container. If you want something to be based on a pixel size us `px`.

You should design your layout so that elements flow and move to new positions as the size of the screen changes. You should read about using `@media()` in css. Elements you wan't to have move and based on percentage use `%` and things that you want ridged use `px`

using `@media()` will let you make break points in your style so that you can make hard changes depending on different attributes of your container and display. Using different `@media()` groups to identify different targets for example (phone, tablet, laptop/desktop, tv). You can also set different css depending on display density.

Look into `@media()`:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Look into responsive web design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

ps. people that zoom in or out on a page expect things to not look right. Most of the time they do this on a desktop due to old eyes and expect it to break the style. All they care about in that situation is being able to read the content. I would not put to much stress about how it looks with any other zoom value than 100%. Zooming on a phone or tablet will not have this same effect and should have very little problems with your design. but assuming your going to do responsive design there will be no need for a user to zoom on a phone or tablet. If your user has to zoom on a phone or tablet you did not make a good responsive design.

Comment: If I use px instead of percentages, will I need to make different layout for every display resolution?