# To align the same image to left, floating with the text in monitor screen, and to center, away from the text in mobile screen. How?

Tags: html, image, alignment, media-queries

I'm developing a responsive article in one HTML file.

Check my CSS and HTML examples, you can view how it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/mnj0060e/1/

In any monitor screen, I align that image to left, floating with the text. But in any mobile screen, the image gets smaller, I don't know how to align the same image to center, keeping the image's size, away from the text. For example:

[image]

I know I should use CSS instead of HTML, because `<img>` isn't supported in HTML5, I would create:

```
img {
height: 40%;
width: 40%;
float: left;
vertical-align: none;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  img {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    float: center;
    vertical-align: none;
  }
}
```

The problem is that this tag `img` applies to all the images. I want it to apply to each one image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what your attempting you could change the styling if its under `600px` and for anything over then use `@media(min-width:600px)` for larger sizes.

```
@media(max-width:599px){//smaller than 600px
   img{
    height: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    float:left;
   }
}

@media(min-width:600px){}//600px and bigger
```

what you have is your using `max-width:600px` so that would apply for everything under or equal to `600px`. If you want it to apply to `600px` and above use `min-width:600px`.

If all you want is to have the image to push the text down under it all the time and take up the center of the screen all the time no matter what the screen size is then just do the following.

```
#myImageId{
   display:block;
   margin:2px auto 2px auto;
}
```

There is an infant ways to target an element for styling. If the element has an id you can target the id as followed.

```
#this_is_my_img_id{
//great things are going to happen
}
```

or you can target a class

```
.my_cool_img_class{
//just the facts
}
```

or an attribute

```
<img coolPic="true"/>

img[coolPic]{}
```

or

```
img[coolPic=true]{}
```

or you can select it based on its location

```
<div id="myCoolPost">
   <img />
   <img />
</div>

#myCoolPost img:nth-child(2){}
```

you can also combine them all together along with traversing the dom

```
#myCoolPost .centerBlock:nth-child(2) img[hasCoolFactor]{}
```

Comment: @patrick-w-mcmahon Thank you! But as for the float, no, I don't want to align the same image to left, but to center, away from the text and I want to autosize the image in any mobile screen. I don't want to apply the `img` to all the images, but only to one image (Presley's photo).

Comment: maybe if you show the html page your attempting to change and identify what you want to change about the display that would help show what your final objective is.

Comment: I want it centered no matter what the size of the screen, but only in @media query as you've seen this image's example. In any monitor screen, I want to keep the same image to left, based on a set width and to float with the text.

Comment: not exactly what your asking but read my answer to the following question. I have provided a lot of details on layout out and using responsive design. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28223074/absolute-html-layout-is-broken-when-zooming/28223433#28223433

Comment: If you have any questions on responsive design just send me a message.

Comment: Ah, my HTML document is my autobiography book. It's intimate. But you can check JSFiddle's link that I gave here, just copy and paste CSS and HTML on a HTML file. Resize the browser window and see how the image is.

Comment: So do you want the image to be center no matter the size of screen and to push the text under it? Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Ah, as I was reading, do I have to replace percentages for pixels? Yes, it's correct, but only in any mobile screen. I also want to apply it only to one image, for avoiding that it apply to all the images (because if I apply the CSS tag ìmg` to one image as centered, all the images will be centered).

Comment: @ media (min-width: 600px) { #myImageId:img {
   display:block;
   margin:2px auto 2px auto;
} Is it correct?

Comment: @media(min-width:600px) will only apply when the display is 600px or bigger. and so that css will not apply to 599px and lower. but if that's what you want it will center on 600px and bigger.

Comment: The `img[coolPic]{}` worked, but the image doesn't autosize when I resized the browser windows from 599 to 400. In monitor screen, the image invaded or bypassed the note body. Check my JSFiddle's update: http://jsfiddle.net/mnj0060e/3/

Comment: use percentages for example width:100%;height:100%; this will take up the full width and height of the parent element.

Comment: Thank you a lot. And how to fix the image that invaded the note body when I resized the browser windows to more or less than 1000px?

Comment: use the following css attributs: max-width, min-width, max-height, min-hight

Comment: It doesn't work. It keeps bypassing the note body. Check the capture: http://i.imgur.com/4JyEHw6.png. I want to keep the image too away from the note body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69856/discussion-between-gustavo-reis-costa-and-patrick-w-mcmahon).

Comment: stop floating the image

Comment: avoid float like the plague

Comment: Ah, keeping display:block and after removing the float, there's much white space. The image is still aligned with one paragraph. Check: http://i.imgur.com/q19ZvER.png

Comment: display:block;width:100%;

Comment: Yeah, it's solved. I learned float is a plague. You were right!

Comment: most of the time you want to use float replace it with position:(relative,fixed,absolute);

Comment: I tested on my autobiography, it worked. Applying `display:block` and `width:100%` worked on any mobile screen. It's OK! But in the monitor screen, with `width: 100%,`, it filled the image in the monitor screen, then I reduced for 40%, but with `display:block, the image is on right. I applied the position, the image 40% isn't positioned well with the text. Check:

//** any monitor screen - the image with the text **//

img[bebe] {
   display: block
   width: 40%;
   margin: 2px 10px 5px auto;
   position: relative;
}

Comment: And //** any mobile screen - filling the image in any mobile screen **//
@media (min-width: 599px) {
  img[bebe] {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 2px 10px 5px auto;
  }
}

Comment: See what I want! Check OMG Ubuntu page's link: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/11/see-install-use-emoji-symbols-ubuntu-linux and see the right-floated image and other resized or filled and center images in this page. Test in monitor and mobile screens.

Comment: This may help. http://www.amazon.com/PROGRAMMING-GUIDE-BEGINNERS-Bonus-Content-ebook/dp/B00RN7862C/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1422631913&sr=1-1&keywords=css+beginner